# Bash: Write a script which will check numeric differences, how is it done?

Tags: bash, shell

I've been given a task to monitor the proxy servers in my company.
There's a command I wrote which checks the proxy cache sync status and outputs this:

```
[root@bmark1 ~]# check ny4a
 #===# NY4A: #===#
      7 36079435
      3 36079441
Would you like to view specific list? [y/n] y
     [java] ny4aproxy5.company.com,36079435
     [java] ny4aproxy4.company.com,36079435
     [java] ny4aproxy12.company.com,36079441
     [java] ny4aproxy11.company.com,36079435
     [java] ny4aproxy3.company.com,36079435
     [java] ny4aproxy2.company.com,36079435
     [java] ny4aproxy1.company.com,36079435
     [java] ny4aproxy10.company.com,36079435
     [java] ny4aproxy9.company.com,36079441
     [java] ny4aproxy13.company.com,36079441
 #===# The check is based on file: /workspace/repository/proxyui/proxy_list.csv  #===#
[root@bmark1 ~]#
```

The check command returns the size of the cache file on each one of the servers.

Best practice is for all files to have the same size or with a little delta.
In some points, a few proxy servers are getting out of sync and their cache file size gets stuck and not being updated.

So you can see in the output of my command that there are 7 servers with a cache file size of: 36079435 bytes and there are 3 more servers which are out of sync, with a cache file size of 36079435.
I want to write a script/check which will find if any servers have a difference in cache file size greater than 10%.

I know how to parse the cache file sizes but not sure how to write the script and get the 10% diff indication.
Can you please assist me?

Comment: You could use `bc` to do the math

Comment: Can you please be more specific than that? Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to make an assumption that the largest cache file is the benchmark to compare against?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your own command generates this stdout:

```
 [java] ny4aproxy5.company.com,36079435
 [java] ny4aproxy4.company.com,36079435
 [java] ny4aproxy12.company.com,36079441
 [java] ny4aproxy11.company.com,36079435
 [java] ny4aproxy3.company.com,36079435
 [java] ny4aproxy2.company.com,36079435
 [java] ny4aproxy1.company.com,36079435
 [java] ny4aproxy10.company.com,36079435
 [java] ny4aproxy9.company.com,36079441
 [java] ny4aproxy13.company.com,30079441
```

The following command returns only the caches that are under the threshold:

```
yourcommand | awk -F, -v max=`yourcommand | awk -F, 'OFS=","{if ($2>max) max=$2}END {print max}'` '{if (($2/max)<0.9) print "outside threshold: " $0 }'
```

I've taken the liberty to change the last cache number to give an indicative <90% example. Output:

```
outside threshold:  [java] ny4aproxy13.company.com,30079441
```

or if you want to know all the percentages:

```
yourcommand | awk -F, -v max=`yourcommand | awk -F, 'OFS=","{if ($2>max) max=$2}END {print max}'` '{print $0, (max-$2)/max*100 }'
```

Output:

```
 [java] ny4aproxy5.company.com,36079435 1.663e-05
 [java] ny4aproxy4.company.com,36079435 1.663e-05
 [java] ny4aproxy12.company.com,36079441 0
 [java] ny4aproxy11.company.com,36079435 1.663e-05
 [java] ny4aproxy3.company.com,36079435 1.663e-05
 [java] ny4aproxy2.company.com,36079435 1.663e-05
 [java] ny4aproxy1.company.com,36079435 1.663e-05
 [java] ny4aproxy10.company.com,36079435 1.663e-05
 [java] ny4aproxy9.company.com,36079441 0
 [java] ny4aproxy13.company.com,30079441 16.63
```

**Explanation:**

`yourcommand | awk` : This bit pipes the stdout of your custom command to awk

`awk -F,`: declares the input delimiter as a comma

`-v max=...`: since we need to iterate through the output twice to first get max then compare with max, we have to feed an awk operation to find max to the second awk operation. I.e. get max via first awk function in backticks and pass variable 'max' to second awk function via -v flag.

`{if ($2>max) max=$2}END {print max}`: simple loop to find max value

`{print $0, (max-$2)/max*100 }`: calculate percentage difference from max and print original row + append percentage

`if (($2/max)<0.9) print "outside than threshold: " $0`: do a simple check to see if ratio of cache size is at least 90% of max. If not, print the 'offending' line

Comment: Nice, can you please explain what you did?

Comment: Fixed the script and added some explanations.

Comment: I should have spelled the question differently, but you did answer it, thanks.